# wso2 mqtt subprotocol handler

Tags: websocket, wso2, mqtt, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm trying to connect a websocket client to a websocket endpoint via wso2 enterprise integrator. The connection should support MQTT.

The problem is the subprotocol comming from the frontend is mqtt or mqttv3.1. This is not supported out of the box by wso2ei. Therefor I wanted to write my own subprotocol handler. But I'm getting errors when trying to use it.

Questions:

- How to fix the error
- How do I control headers

My class

```
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketFrame;
import org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.websocket.AbstractSubprotocolHandler;

public class MqttSubprotocolHandler extends AbstractSubprotocolHandler {

    public MqttSubprotocolHandler() {
        super.setSubprotocolIdentifier("mqttv3.1");
    }

    public boolean handle(ChannelHandlerContext context, WebSocketFrame frame, String subscriberPath) {
        context.channel().writeAndFlush(frame.retain());
        return false;
    }

}
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.lminds</groupId>
    <artifactId>WSO2dropins</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>wso2-nexus</id>
            <name>WSO2 internal Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.synapse</groupId>
            <artifactId>synapse-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2-wso2v2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2.wso2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1.wso2v10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.stub</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.mediation</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.75</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2.wso2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2.wso2v13</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wso2/carbon/inbound/endpoint/protocol/websocket/AbstractSubprotocolHandler
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClassHoldingLock(ClasspathManager.java:638)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:613)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:574)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:492)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:465)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:452)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.websocket.SubprotocolBuilderUtil.stringToSubprotocolHandlers(SubprotocolBuilderUtil.java:89)
        at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.websocket.management.WebsocketEndpointManager.startListener(WebsocketEndpointManager.java:133)
        at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.websocket.management.WebsocketEndpointManager.startEndpoint(WebsocketEndpointManager.java:74)
        at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.websocket.InboundWebsocketListener.init(InboundWebsocketListener.java:52)
        at org.apache.synapse.inbound.InboundEndpoint.init(InboundEndpoint.java:79)
        at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.CarbonInboundManagementService.updateInboundEndpoint(CarbonInboundManagementService.java:226)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.java:66)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:169)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.finalizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTransportSender.java:45)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTransportSender.java:77)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:430)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
        at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.stub.InboundAdminStub.updateInboundEndpoint(InboundAdminStub.java:1708)
        at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.ui.internal.InboundManagementClient.updteInboundEndpoint(InboundManagementClient.java:333)
        at org.apache.jsp.inbound.updateInbound_002dajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(updateInbound_002dajaxprocessor_jsp.java:247)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.URLBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(URLBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CSRFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CSRFPreventionFilter.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CRLFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CRLFPreventionFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1760)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1719)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.websocket.AbstractSubprotocolHandler cannot be found by WSO2dropins_1.0_1.0.0
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the package **org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.websocket** is not exported at [1], hence getting the NoClassDefFoundError as above for [2].

[1] - https://github.com/wso2/carbon-mediation/blob/v4.6.75/components/inbound-endpoints/org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint/pom.xml#L120

[2] - https://github.com/wso2/carbon-mediation/blob/v4.6.75/components/inbound-endpoints/org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/inbound/endpoint/protocol/websocket/AbstractSubprotocolHandler.java